# Creating a sheet that doesn't block interaction with other windows

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, window, modal-dialog, nspanel

As far as I know, sheets modal for a certain window without "freezing" the app can only be `NSSavePanel`s, `NSOpenPanel`s, and `NSAlert`s windows (since NSAlert isn't a NSWindow or NSPanel subclass but it has an associated window); if I wanted a generic `NSPanel` to be such a sheet, for example, I couldn't prevent it from freezing the app since the only (?) way to start that sheet is using

```
[NSApp beginSheet:modalForWindow:modalDelegate:didEndSelector:contextInfo:]
```

So, is there any way to set a generic panel as a sheet without freezing the entire app?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here.  Are you wanting the `NSPanel` to be completely non-modal?

Comment: I want it to be a sheet (= attached to another window) without freezing the app

Comment: You've already found the way to do that, use `-[beginSheet:modalForWindow:modalDelegate:didEndSelector:contextInfo:]`.  What's not working for you?

Comment: The app gets frozen doing so: it waits for the sheet to be closed.

Comment: How many windows do you have open?   The sheet will prevent doing anything else in that window, but if you have second window open in the app, it should operate just fine.

Comment: Two windows: if I start that sheet modal for one of them, I cannot interact with the other window until the sheet is closed.

Comment: That's strange, it should work.

Comment: From NSApp's docs: "While the application is in the run loop, it does not respond to any other events (including mouse, keyboard, or window-close events) unless they are associated with the sheet."

Comment: Badly phrased documentation.   I am staring at code here which has been working since 2008 and we use this in a dozen different places for window-modal presentations.

Comment: [Sheet conceptual docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Sheets/Concepts/AboutSheets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001043-BABFIBIA).   Are you using separate documents for each? If not, maybe it's seeing the documents as the same and handling it as document-modal.

Comment: For clarity, our sheets are based on `NSPanel`, so you shouldn't have a problem because of the `NSWindow` type.

Comment: My fault: there still was a [NSApp runModalForWindow:] around.

Comment: That'd explain it ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-[beginSheet:modalForWindow:modalDelegate:didEndSelector:contextInfo:]` for you with an `NSPanel` without difficulty.

However, if you have multiple windows on the same document, `NSApp` will block all windows within that document, since it's actually Document modal, not Window modal.